# Large SATA drives in HP ProLiant 585 G5 server?

Tags: sata, drive

I have been reading in the manual that the 8, 2.5 hard drive slots use up to 500gb SAS each, for a maximum of 4TB. So my question is, what if I wanted to use one regular 1TB 2.5 sata hard drive in one of the slots? Would the server recognize it, or any large 2TB+ drive for that matter if connected externally from a caddy to usb?

Comment: This is for a small business? we just got this server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any SAS or SATA 2.5" disk in this server.

If you use SATA, the speeds will be downshifted to 1.5Gbps.

For this disk form-factor, SAS drives provide greater capacity. You can get them in 146, 300, 450, 600, 900 and 1200GB capacities.

Don't mess with USB on a server this old... I believe it's limited to USB 2.0 speeds.

Comment: so can I use a 1TB 2.5 disk? will the server read this?

Comment: Did you read what I wrote above?

Comment: Yes I did read what you said, but you said any! but not all servers like large drives, and the manual says 500GB max per slot and total 4TB, my fear is wasting money on drives we cant use, but if you say any size will work then thanks for your answer, as for speed we intend to use an addon usb3.0 pci-e card as the G5 model supports x16.